# After crop image not show properly

Tags: php, image, jcrop

I am trying to crop my image with jcrop.my crop process works but after crop image height and width not works correctly.Image always show with blank shadow.

[after crop image look like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwEGKh5XEyYjd3JFdTlUYnhVZUk/view?usp=sharing)

[original image look like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwEGKh5XEyYjV2dsb2pVRmFLQ0E/view?usp=sharing)

my code is

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
 $targ_w =  $_POST['w'];$targ_h = $_POST['h'];
 $jpeg_quality = 90;
 $src = 'amazonaws/'.$_POST['rq'];

  $type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($src,"."),1));
  if($type == 'jpeg') $type = 'jpg';
  switch($type){
    case 'bmp': $img_r = imagecreatefromwbmp($src); break;
    case 'gif': $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src); break;
    case 'jpg': $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); break;
    case 'png': $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src); break;
    default : return "Unsupported picture type!";
  } 

    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );


  if($type == "gif" or $type == "png"){
    imagecolortransparent($dst_r, imagecolorallocatealpha($dst_r, 0, 0, 0, 127));
    imagealphablending($dst_r, false);
    imagesavealpha($dst_r, true);
  } 
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);


 switch($type){
    case 'bmp': imagewbmp($dst_r,$src); break;
    case 'gif': imagegif($dst_r,$src); break;
    case 'jpg': imagejpeg($dst_r,$src,$jpeg_quality); break;
    case 'png': imagepng($dst_r,$src); break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is imagecopyresampled() prototype :

```
bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

In your script, you specify that

```
$targ_w =  $_POST['w']; $targ_h = $_POST['h'];
```

And when you call

```
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
```

You are telling the copy function that the source image has the same size as the dest image

You need to get the original image dimensions with

```
list($src_width, $src_height, $src_type, $src_attr) = getimagesize($src) ;
```

and to use those dimensions in the copy function

```
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$src_width,$src_height);
```